# Multiple addon domains, one htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, addon-domain

Lets say, my root domain name is **main.com** and I have two addon domains: **addon1.com** and **addon2.com**.

My script is already ready and I can see my websites like this:

```
    www.main.com/show.php?domain=addon1.com
```

But, what I want is displaying websites through their domains. I mean when I open addon1.com, I want to see output of **show.php?domain=addon1.com**. Also these two domains are added as addon domain and their directory are:

```
    main.com/addon1.com/
    main.com/addon2.com/
```

I wrote a htaccess file to root folder (main.com/.htaccess)

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.addon1\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /show.php?domain=addon1.com&$1

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.addon2\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /show.php?domain=addon2.com&$1
```

But I'm getting 500 interval error. Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are looping. The `/show.php` is going back through the rewrite engine and looping indefinitely. You need to add conditions so they don't loop:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.addon1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/show.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /show.php?domain=addon1.com&$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.addon2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/show.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /show.php?domain=addon2.com&$1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is trying to load **main.com/addon1.com/show.php**, show.php is in the root folder (main.com/show.php).

Answer (score 0):

You needed to include "**RewriteBase**" to help out.

```
# tell mod_rewrite to activate and give base for relative paths
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase   /

# for the active site in hosting root folder,
# tell it not to look for a subfolder by skipping next rule
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?main\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$         - [S=1]

# the domain-name = sub-folder automation
# thus addon-domain.com in /addon-domain(\.com)?/
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ([^.]+)\.com
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$         %1/$1 [L]

# to answer your question swap the above 
# domain-name = sub-folder automation for this rule
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ([^.]+)\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/show.php
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$         /show.php?domain=%1&$1 [L]
# although, the above line may require this instead
  RewriteRule .              main.com/show.php?domain=%1&$1 [L]
```